# JQuery Fullcalendar display full title despite being merely 30 minutes event

Tags: fullcalendar

If I set an `end` time to an event, then the plugin draws the event rubric in accordance with it. Problem is, if event is too short, user can't read the title...

[image]

How can I make it "override" the `end` time in these cases and display the full title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Agenda view you can use agendaEventMinHeight to get your desired result. You won't actually override the end time, but directly override the size of the event-box.

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/agendaEventMinHeight